# UITextField is not working in IOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios8

`UITextField` is not working in iOS8, I am unable to see keyboard when clicking on text box and not see any crash. But it is working fine in iOS7 devices. 
I am using following code:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TF_MSG_ ENTER", @"") message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TF_CANCEL_TEXT", @"") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"TF_MSG_ OK", @""), nil];

    UITextField *txBookmarkName = nil;

  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0)
  {
    txBookmarkName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0f, 45.0f, 260.0f, 25.0f)];
    myAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    txBookmarkName = [myAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
  }
  else
  {
    txBookmarkName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0f, 45.0f, 260.0f, 25.0f)];
    IF_PRE_IOS4 (
                 [txBookmarkName release], txBookmarkName = nil;
                 txBookmarkName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0f, 65.0f, 260.0f, 25.0f)];
                 );
  }
    [txBookmarkName setDelegate:self];
    [txBookmarkName setText:nameLabel.text];
    myAlert.tag=TF_TAG_TEXT_FIELD_RENAME;
    [txBookmarkName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txBookmarkName becomeFirstResponder];
    [txBookmarkName setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    txBookmarkName.tag=TF_TAG_TEXTFIELD;
    [myAlert addSubview: txBookmarkName];
    [myAlert setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300,50)];
    IF_PRE_IOS4 (
                             CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 85.0f);
                             [myAlert setTransform: t];
                             );
    [myAlert show];
    [txBookmarkName release];
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 7.0)
    [myAlert release];
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using a Simulator to test this?

Comment: It is not working in simulator as well as device also...

Comment: is the userInteractionEnabled and enabled property of the UITextField set to YES?

Comment: Which device, which version of iOS 8 (e.g. beta, GM?).

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this code example, not least that it includes if statement for earlier versions of iOS. Can you slim it down. You should also try a simple test case for a textfield and not much else in a new project. You should see that UITextFields work just fine.

Comment: The reason you're getting down voted is because you're saying UITextField doesn't work in iOS 8. This is demonstrably not true - just look at existing iOS 8 phones, with existing iOS 8 apps using UITextFields. Consequently it's the kind of claim that needs a lot of evidence to support it - i.e. lots of details about your particular environment - and a proper code sample.

Answer (score 2):

check this:

Open Simulator.

Go to Hardware.

Then select Keyboard.

Then choose iOS Users Same Layout As OS X

**Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> iOS Users Same Layout As OS X**

[image]

it's working :)